# Access PHP Array within jQuery (Ajax, JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following PHP code which encodes a PHP array:

**Code**

```
$js_array = json_encode($tmp);
```

**Output**

```
{
 "frfgt55":["ABC","frfgt55","Aberdeen"],
 "vfrgt6":["ABC","vfrgt6","Birmingham"],
 "vbgtfdh67":["XYZ","vbgtfdh67","Leeds"],
 "vfe5gb":["XYZ","vfe5gb","Bristol"],...
}
```

What I am struggling with is to then access this within a jQuery script.  I know I should be making use of `$.getJSON` but I am struggling with its implementation as my Ajax knowledge is limited.  I cannot see how this would access the variable that as been encoded.

**Ajax code**

```
$.getJSON('../_client/index.php', function(data) {
    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
});
```

Any advice, feedback and comments welcomed.

Comment: @ex3v - the question is clear - how do i access the php array that I have encoded within a jQuery script.  I've also added the Ajax code but as my knowledge is limited I am struggling to understand how this works.

Comment: make sure you output the header('Content-Type: application/json'); before any other output, data should contain  data.frfgt55[0] etc....

Comment: What's your question then? ^^ Anyways, you cannot _access a PHP array via JS_: what you do is to make a HTTP request to a server, which will respond with an HTTP response. Browser has no knowledge about how such response was generated, it just parses it [being it a JSON string], and does its business with it.

Comment: @moonwave99 - 'Access PHP Array within jQuery (Ajax, JSON)' - question is pretty clear.

Comment: @Homer_J what is your problem then? Did your attempt work? If not, what errors did you get?

Comment: @moonwave99 - as I state, quite clearly, in the question - I don't know `how` to access it - the above doesn't work for me - no outputs at all.  I also state that I `think` I need to make use of Ajax but that my knowledge is limited.  Once I have access to the array - I can then use the information the array contains - I took that as a given when asking the question.

Comment: Well then the answer is "you can't at all" - you can just make a request to the server, but the response won't share any connection with the original PHP array. Your example [which btw is totally correct] makes a request, but doesn't do anything with the `data`, so it is normal that you have no output at all. Issue a `console.log(data)` inside the `$.getJSON` callback, then we can help you further.

Comment: @moonwave99 added the `console.log(data);` to the code but there is no output in the console log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I well understood your needs you can access data with:

```
$.getJSON('../_client/index.php', function(data) {
    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
    console.info(data.frfgt55); //accessing the first item of the array
});
```

---

EDIT

In order to handle success and error code I suggest you to use the promise interface and so replace the current $.getJSON() code with:

```
$.getJSON('../_client/index.php')
.success(function(response) { console.info(response); alert("success"); })
.fail(function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.info(error); alert("error"); });
```

Comment: It should be `data.frfgt55[0]` unless you want the entire first array.

Comment: It could be everything...I've just given @Homer_J a response in order to help him find his way, since he didn't know how to access data

Comment: Thanks for this - added to my code and also added `alert(data.frfgt55);` but no output at all.

Comment: Hmm what's the console output of `console.info(data);` ? In case it's empty then probably you're not echoing the response array? just my assumption..

Comment: It's not displaying any data (removed the previous error that was linked to other code)

Comment: are you echoing `$js_array` from the php page? Are the json object `$js_array` or the array `$tmp` empty? try with a `var_dump($js_array);` and let me know the result

Comment: Tried echoing and var_dumping but still nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56962/discussion-between-ilpaijin-and-homer-j).

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct then check this code it will help you

```
$.getJSON('../_client/index.php', function(data) {
    for(var key in data) { // In comment check first loop data for each record.
       // key = 'frfgt55'; // For 1st loop
        var yourArrayRecord = data[key]; // For 1st loop <- ["ABC","frfgt55","Aberdeen"]
        var perticularValue1 = yourArrayRecord[0]; // For 1st loop <- "ABC"
        var perticularValue2 = yourArrayRecord[1]; // For 1st loop <- "frfgt55"
        var perticularValue3 = yourArrayRecord[2]; // For 1st loop <- "Aberdeen"
    }
});
```